# ArcGlobe not sitting on Globe Surface

Tags: arcglobe, 3d-analyst

I have gone through the process of bringing a SketchUp model into ArcScene utilizing Edit Placement on the 3D Editor window. The model appears to have come in great. However, it is floating slightly above my base parcel layer. Is there a way to get the multipatch 3D layer not to float slightly above another layer? I have even selected Floating on Custom Surface Elevation 30 m and yet it remains hovering above the ground. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is your surface vertically exaggerated?

Comment: Just getting back to this, but the problem was the units had to be in meters I believe.